# Implementing `Monoidal Option`

Tags: haskell

Looking at [Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Definition_2)'s definition of `Monoidal`:

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  unit :: f ()
  (**) :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
```

Let's say that I have the following `Optional` instance:

```
data Option a = Some a 
                | None deriving Show

instance Functor Option where
   fmap _ None     = None
   fmap f (Some x) = Some (f x)
```

Now, I'd like to implement `Monoidal Option`:

```
instance Monoidal Option where
  unit = ???
```

However, I'm not sure what the instance's type is for `unit`.

Does `unit` have a type of `f ()` for *every* `Monoidal`?

Also, what's the meaning of `f ()`? I know that I'm missing something - it's not clear to me how `f ()` is a useful type.

Comment: Better to say that for every `Monoidal f`, there's a `unit` of type `f ()`. `()` is often called unit - it's a type with exactly one value, which is also written `()`. You can think of it as the tuple of zero elements, like `(a,b)` is the type of tuples with two elements. `f ()` can be useful for a number of reasons. For example, `putStrLn "hello, world" :: IO ()`. Everything has *some* type, but sometimes an action doesn't calculate a useful value, and having it return `()` is a good sign that it's more interesting for its side-effects.

Comment: Alternately, if `f` is a `Functor`, having a value of type `f ()` gives you a way of having a value of type `f a` for any `a` you can provide an example of. For instance, if `mkA :: a`, then `fmap (const mkA) unit :: (Functor f, Monoidal f) => f a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` is a type constructor, and in this case it is `Option` so `f ()` is `Option ()`. There are two possibilities for this value - `Nothing` or `Some ()`. Given the laws that `unit` should obey i.e. the left and right identity laws, you should return `Some ()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it helps if you think about the actual types involved in the instance. Recall that the `f` in the `class` definition is `Option` in the instance, so:

```
instance Monoidal Option where
  -- unit :: Option ()
  unit = ???
  -- (**) :: Option a -> Option b -> Option (a,b)
  None   ** None   = ???
  Some a ** None   = ???
  None   ** Some b = ???
  Some a ** Some b = ???
```